# select a value from different table based on conditions in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'm trying to select a value from a different table based on current table values and condition

Table 1:

| C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 | 5 |
| 1 | 6 | 6 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 |

Table 2:

| D1 | D2 | D3 | D4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | Value1 |
| 1 | 4 | 5 | Value2 |
| 1 | 6 | 8 | Value3 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | Value4 |
| 2 |  |  | Value5 |

And Im trying to get the below expected result table a single line sql
Results:

| C1 | C2 | C3 | D4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | Value1 |
| 1 | 4 | 5 | Value2 |
| 1 | 6 | 6 |  |
| 2 | 3 | 3 | Value5 |

The condition is to pick D4 value only
 `(C1=D1 and C2=D2 and C3=D3) matches then D4` or when   `C1=D1 matches then D4 else null for all`

I tried inner join and also case statement but no success

Here is the [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oDmsCCvPaCfcBRVQDzzZ5t/0) i had created

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a `left join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.d4
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.C1 = t2.D1 and
        (t1.C2 = t2.D2 or t2.D2 is null) and
        (t1.C3 = t2.D3 or t2.D3 is null);
```

Note:  It is a little hard to tell from the explanation if you need for both `D2` and `D3` to be `NULL`.  If so:

```
select t1.*, t2.d4
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.C1 = t2.D1 and
        (t1.C2 = t2.D2 and t1.C3 = t2.D3 or
         t2.D2 is null and t2.D3 is null
        );
```

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fmRDyNv1cuTrkJciFW4An4/0) is the fiddle.

Comment: 2nd solution is what I'm looking for. If the first condition is null then look for C1=D1 and even if that fails leave it as null.

Comment: Can we do is null condition on D4 column meaning
If First condition (C1=D1 & C2=D2 & C3=D3) satisfy, but D4 value pulled from the t2 is null then look for 2nd condition (C1=D1) and pull D4 from that if that value also is null then leave it as null

Here is the fiddle (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ehyjtuUSr6NgeFS8Gbspr9/1)

Comment: @fonr . . . Could you ask a new question with a clear explanation and sample data?

Comment: I asked again with more detail about what Im trying to achieve. Thanks.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67472681/select-non-null-value-of-multiple-condition-in-inner-join-of-sql